# mysql random entries from the top200

Tags: php, mysql

is there a better way to return random entries from the TOP 200 bestselling tshirts (tshirt_sales from shop_tshirts) that could just query just 6 entries instead of 200 ?

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM shop_tshirts WHERE shop = 'nidieunimaitre' AND online='1' ORDER BY tshirt_sales DESC LIMIT 200";

$Result = mysql_query($SQL)
    or die('A error occured: ' . mysql_error());

$Rows = array();

while ($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Result))
    $Rows[] = $Row;

shuffle($Rows);

$i = 0;
foreach($Rows as $Data){
$i++;
    if($i >= 6) { break; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
      (SELECT * 
       FROM shop_tshirts 
       WHERE shop = 'nidieunimaitre' AND online='1' 
       ORDER BY tshirt_sales DESC 
       LIMIT 200) as tableAlis
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 6;
```

Return first 200 results and after order by rand and return only six results.

Comment: A error occured: Every derived table must have its own alias